# How can I reference parameters with same name but in different methods to their respective methods in global substitutions

Tags: documentation, python-sphinx, cross-reference

I have multiple methods but most of them have 2 parameters in common i.e. params with same name in different methods. I want to reference that parameter in other param docstring through substitutions in global.rst, I wasn't able to find a way to link to the parameter of that specific method, instead I was forced to specify exact method and param name.

Here's the substitution in global.rst
`` .. |foo| replace:: Replace with :paramref:`foo`. ``

And heres a example class with methods with same params:

```
class FooFather():
    def foo1(foo, bar):
        """
        foo (:obj:`Any`): this is foo
        bar (:obj:`Any`): |foo|
        """

    def foo2(foo, bar):
        """
        foo (:obj:`Any`): this is foo
        bar (:obj:`Any`): |foo|
        """
```

Now I can't link to the foo of that specific method from bar, I have to explicitly specify the method of the parameter to link to, like so:
`` .. |foo| replace:: Replace with :paramref:`FooFather.foo1.foo`. ``

I want that foo2's documentation links to foo2's foo param and similar. Is there any way around this?

Comment: If you are using the https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-paramlinks/ extension, you should say so in the question.